# Trouble with raycasting in a React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, three.js

So I am trying to get a spinning avocado to change color when the user hovers their cursor over it. I got the spinning avocado part down, but I’m struggling with the raycasting part and I suspect it’s because I’m trying to use it in a useEffect hook. But I have no idea what other ways I can do this. The pointermove event listener is working, but I think the problem may be in the requestAnimationFrame. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
const Three3d = () => {
  const threedRef = useRef(document.createElement('div'));
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

  useEffect(() => {
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    threedRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(light);

    let gltf: any;
    loader.load(
      process.env.PUBLIC_URL + './models/Avocado.glb',
      function (result: any) {
        gltf = result;
        gltf.scene.scale.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);

        camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
      },
      undefined,
      function (error: any) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

    function onPointerMove(event: any) {
      pointer.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      pointer.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    }
    function render() {
      raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects<any>(scene.children);
      for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
      }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    window.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      scene.rotation.y += 0.01;
      scene.rotation.x += 0.01;

      controls.update();

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
  }, []);
```